# delete their own files in document library sync locally

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business

In my site i have a document library. am syncing that library in my laptop.

so here is my question.

if i tried to delete files created by other users  it should not delete.
i can delete files which am created in that library (in my laptop sync folder).

if anybody deletes others files then it should not reflect in documents library.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to achieve this.It's by design that if you delete files from local Machine then it will delete the file from SharePoint Library.

I would recommend that you use permission level to restrict users delete files. Create a new permission level and uncheck "Delete Item" permissions. Grant the users this permission level.